# Adding dynamic data to searchable multi select jquery using spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring

I am using Jquery script from this [website](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown.html).

Controller in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/method2/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String method3(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("data") Data data) {
        model.addAttribute("data",new Data());
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        array.add("Variable 1-Definition 1");
        array.add("variable 2 - Definition 2");
        array.add("variable 3-Definition 3");
        model.addAttribute("variableList", array);
        System.out.print(array);
        return VIEWS_LOCATION +"/secondPage";
    }
```

- JSP Page:

> 

```js
<script>
var abc = $('.demo').dropdown({
 multipleMode : 'label',
 
});
console.log("doc load"+abc);

</script>
```

```html
 <div class="demo" id="dropdown1">
<form:select style="display: none" name="" id="values" path="name" multiple="true">
 <form:option value="variable11" selected="true">variable1</form:option>
 <form:option value="variable2" >variable2</form:option>
 <form:option value="variable3" >variable3</form:option>
 <form:options items="${variableList}" />   
</form:select>
 </div>
```

The webpage is attached below.
List of selected options appear in the search box

[As you can see Variable1-definition1 is a dynamic value, which when clicked cannot be seen in the search box, but it is already selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wUtV.png)

Dynamic data may contain upto 500 entries which is to be read from a file. 3 variables are added just for representation purpose.Help me in adding the dynamic data to the dropdown. Thanks!

Comment: Refer solution here as well https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer!

The issue with the earlier approach is that JS couldn't locate the exact element which is selected(I am not sure, how it is able to change the css of the selected elements and search results are working fine).

So, I have made some changes to the code, which now is working fine.

Controller: Instead of sending an array, I am passing a hashmap, which makes indexing easier.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/method2/submit",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String method3(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("data") Data data) {
        model.addAttribute("name",data.getName());
        model.addAttribute("data",new Data());
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("1","Variable 1-Definition 1");
        map.put("2","variable 2 - Definition 2");
        map.put("3","variable 3-Definition 3");
        model.addAttribute("variableList", map);
        System.out.println(map);
        return VIEWS_LOCATION +"/secondPage";
    }
```

```html
<c:forEach var="item" items="${variableList}">
    <option value="${item.key}">${item.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Also, In the JSP Value is passed as a unique number which makes the JS to identify the exact element selected from the dropdown.
Now, The output looks like,
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T81XB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow one, this should work for you.

```
<form:select  name="" id="values" path="name" multiple="true" items="${variableList}" />
```